# Set ajax MaskedEditExtender mask by Jquery script in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

Is there a way to set Ajax MaskedEditExtender Mask by jquery secript.
I'm using asp.net!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this example its about how to use java script to set ajax controls properties.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1472961/3424520.aspx#3424520